# Probability - What is the probability that a randomly selected bicyclist who tests negative for steroids actually uses steroids

Tags: probability

Suppose  that  $8\%$  of  all  bicycle  racers  use  steroids,  that  a  bicyclist  who  uses  steroids  tests  positive  for steroids $96\%$ of the time, and that a bicyclists who does not use steroids tests positive for steroids $1\%$ of the time.

(a) What is the probability that a randomly selected bicyclist who tests positive for steroids actually uses steroids?

(b)What is the probability that a randomly selected bicyclist who tests negative for steroids actually uses steroids?

I have idea of part a) of this problem. I got answer as 0.893 but I am not able to change it for negative test. Please help how to proceed

Comment: Your answer is correct. Strange that you can't repea the same for the part b. You may want to draw a transition tree - starting with two options: "Use steroids" and "Don't use steroids". Then each of them has also two descendants: "Test positive" and "Test negative". Then you should use formula for conditional probability to find probabilities of nodes and after that Bayes (having P(A|B) you will want to find P(B|A)).

But actually I'm commenting to say that 100% of bicycle racers use steroids. It's a sport in which the guys are actually biorobots not even to be compared with common people:)

Comment: @Stan SOrry but for negative I am getting confused in all the events, Please can you show how to proceed , or atleast give me baye's theorem equation for this

Comment: don't know how to add pics to comments. here is kind of a draft [link](http://1drv.ms/1LVvrjM)

Comment: @Stan what are the A and B in the last part, and what exactly would be the part of answer , I am again confused

Comment: ))) hey, man))) A - uses steroids, B - test is negative.

Comment: Is there any reason you do not want the percentage symbols you typed to be visible?

Comment: @Henry No, it was just to highlight

Comment: @Stan  I am getting 0.00028 as asnwer. Is it true ?

Comment: Strange way of highlighting by making it invisible !

Comment: P(uses | neg) = P(neg | uses)*P(uses)/P(neg), right? From the transition tree P(neg) = P(doesn't use)*P(neg | doesn't use) + P(uses)*P(neg|uses), right? I'm getting 0.04*0.08/(0.92*0.99 + 0.08*0.04) =  0.0035. But I could confuse some numbers. Please check

Comment: @Stan (0.04*0.08)*0.08/(0.92*0.99 + 0.08*0.04) = 0.00028  ?  You missed 0.08 in numerator i.e. p(uses)

Comment: P(uses) = 0.08 and P(neg | uses) = 0.04 by you conditions. It says that test gives negative result for steroid user with probability 0.04.

Comment: check the link. I updated pic with complete solution. Hope this helps

Comment: @stan please attach link

Comment: the same one [sol](http://1drv.ms/1LVvrjM)

Answer (score 1):

*Hint*

If you need Bayes' theorem equation for this, you haven't fully grasped it, and you should fall back on a more intuitive approach

Uses steroids $(8\%)\rightarrow$ tests negative $(4\%)\rightarrow$ P(uses steroids $\cap$ tests negative) = ...

Doesn't use steroids $(92\%)\rightarrow$ tests negative $(99\%)\rightarrow$ P(Doesn't use steroids $\cap$ tests negative) =

I think you should be able to continue from here

Or it seems that you can't !

> P(uses steroids $\cap$ tests negative) = $0.32\%$
>
> P(doesn't use steroids $\cap$ tests negative) = $91.08\%$
>
> P(uses steroids | tests negative) = $\dfrac{0.32}{0.32+91.08}$

Answer (score 1):

Pictorial solution. In every diagram but the topmost, we are working in a population of 10000 people to boost intuition.

[image: Steroid usage]

Answer (score 1):

You were able to solve this problem correctly:

> Suppose  that  $8\%$  of  all  bicycle  racers  use  steroids,  that  a  bicyclist  who  uses  steroids  tests  **positive**  for steroids $96\%$ of the time, and that a bicyclist who does not use steroids tests **positive** for steroids $1\%$ of the time.
>
> (a) What is the probability that a randomly selected bicyclist who tests **positive** for steroids actually uses steroids?

So now try solving this problem:

> Suppose  that  $8\%$  of  all  bicycle  racers  use  steroids,  that  a  bicyclist  who  uses  steroids  tests  **negative**  for steroids $4\%$ of the time, and that a bicyclist who does not use steroids tests **negative** for steroids $99\%$ of the time.
>
> (b)What is the probability that a randomly selected bicyclist who tests **negative** for steroids actually uses steroids?

As you can see, it's the exact same problem, except that the word "positive" is changed to "negative" and a couple of the numbers are different.

(This is simply a more explicit exposition of the hint you received in a comment from Stan.)